# How to change the li background color by pressing button (vue3)?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-cli

I'm totally new guy here, so I would really appreciate any help. I need to change the color of the li-element by pressing button. But when I press it, all the li-elements backgrounds are changing.

````
    <div class="app">
        <form class="joke-search">
            <input class="joke-search__field" type="text" placeholder="Lorem...">
        </form>
        <ul class="joke-list">
            <li class="joke-list__item" v-for="(joke, index) in jokes" :key="joke.id" v-bind:class="{ liked: isActive }">
                <div class="joke-list__title"> {{ joke.setup }} {{ joke.delivery }} </div>
                <img class="joke-list__btn" :src="src[currentSrc]" @click="changeImage()">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
           jokes: [
               {id: 1, setup: 'Lorem', delivery: 'Lorem'},
               {id: 2, setup: 'Lorem', delivery: 'Lorem'},
               {id: 3, setup: 'Lorem', delivery: 'Lorem'},
               {id: 4, setup: 'Lorem', delivery: 'Lorem'}
           ],
           src: ['https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DimGA/assets/main/thumbs-up.svg', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DimGA/assets/main/thumbs-up-active.svg'],
           currentSrc: 0,
           isActive: false
        }
        
    }, 
    methods: {
        changeImage(index) {
            this.currentSrc = (this.currentSrc == 0) ? 1 : 0;
            this.isActive = (this.isActive == true) ? false : true
        }
    }

}```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXFGP.png
````

Answer (score 0):

Define another property called `currentImgIndex` which should be set when you click on a list item :

```
data() {
        return {
           jokes: [
               {id: 1, setup: 'Lorem', delivery: 'Lorem'},
               {id: 2, setup: 'Lorem', delivery: 'Lorem'},
               {id: 3, setup: 'Lorem', delivery: 'Lorem'},
               {id: 4, setup: 'Lorem', delivery: 'Lorem'}
           ],
           src: ['https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DimGA/assets/main/thumbs-up.svg', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DimGA/assets/main/thumbs-up-active.svg'],
           currentSrc: 0,
           isActive: false,
           currentImgIndex:-1
        }
   },
  methods: {
        changeImage(index) {
           this.currentImgIndex=index
            this.currentSrc = (this.currentSrc == 0) ? 1 : 0;
            this.isActive = (this.isActive == true) ? false : true
        }
    }
```

in template pass the current index as param to `changeImage` method and bind the class like `v-bind:class="{ liked: index===currentImgIndex}"`:

```
  <li class="joke-list__item" v-for="(joke, index) in jokes" :key="joke.id" v-bind:class="{ liked: index===currentImgIndex}">
                <div class="joke-list__title"> {{ joke.setup }} {{ joke.delivery }} </div>
                <img class="joke-list__btn" :src="src[currentSrc]" @click="changeImage(index)">
            </li>
```